# Работа приложений в фоне win8.1

Tags: windows

У меня есть приложение и оно отображается в нижней панели win8.1, когда оно запущено, когда приложений много, например одну и ту же программу нужно запустить 10 раз, то начинается хаос, как можно оптимизировать это, мне бы конкретно хотелось, чтобы некоторые из этих приложений работали в фоне, если я правильно это называю, т.е., чтобы не отображались в нижней панели, а приложения, с которыми я активно работаю, например, браузер, там отображались, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Это задается самим приложением. Максимум, что вы можете сделать, это покопаться в настройках приложений и поискать пункт типа "Hide from taskbar", как например в Скайпе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]